# Why thepiratebay.se showing the content of /var/www/index.html?

Tags: apache-httpd

I have elementary OS Luna, which is based on ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I have installed apache2 and turned it off. Now when I am opening thepiratebay.se, it is showing the content of `/var/WWW/index.html`.

[image: thepiratebay.se showing the content of /var/www/index.html]

And also the `localhost` is set to `127.0.1.1`, and not `127.0.0.1`.

The thepiratebay.se should show it's own content, but it's is showing what's there in the `/var/www/index.html`.

How can I fix both the issues? Also where can I see the installed apache2? I couldn't find it in the Installed programs of Software Center. Can you also suggest the resources for learning about working with lamp in ubuntu or elementary OS Luna?

Additional info:
By putting `host thepiratebay.se` in terminal I get the below.

`thepiratebay.se has address 194.71.107.27`

I am not able to change the content of index.html, it doesn't allow me to do so.
And I don't know how to change the permissions on that file.

I ran `curl -D headers.txt -o /dev/null http://thepiratebay.se/`
 and I got the following info.

```
curl -D headers.txt -o /dev/null http://thepiratebay.se/
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   177  100   177    0     0   1397      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  172k
```

When I ran `dig thepiratebay.se` in terminal, I got the following info

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.1-P1 <<>> thepiratebay.se
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 59789
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;thepiratebay.se.       IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
thepiratebay.se.    86400   IN  A   127.0.0.1

;; Query time: 42 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Mon Sep 22 09:22:43 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 49
```

And I ran this - `chmod +rw /var/www/index.html`  in terminal, and I got the following info

```
chmod: changing permissions of '/var/www/index.html': Operation not permitted
```

And the file permissions to `/var/www/index.html` are still the same. It isn't allowing me to delete/modify that file.

The following is the content of headers.txt at /home.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 22 Sep 2014 03:54:57 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Last-Modified: Sun, 21 Sep 2014 02:54:24 GMT
ETag: "321e67-b1-5038a73afffed"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 177
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html
X-Pad: avoid browser bug
```

I opened the /var/www/index.html file with nano in terminal, as in

```
sudo nano /var/www/index.html
```

and I could change it's content, and saved successfully, by Ctrl + O and then Enter, and then came out of nano by Ctrl + X.
And then I went to thepiratebay.se and it's now showing the new content of /var/www/index.html file.

Comment: What happens if you change the content of `/var/WWW/index.html`?

Comment: Your internet provider may be redirecting thepiratebay.se to localhost.

Comment: Where is `localhost` set/showing `127.0.1.1`?

Comment: If you've turned apache off, how would it be handling requests?

Comment: Your problem is definitely not with the Apache configuration: Apache shouldn't be involved in the first place, that's where the problem is. What are your proxy settings? Do you get the same effect in all browsers? Does your ISP block thepiratebay.se? Run `curl -D headers.txt -o /dev/null http://thepiratebay.se/` and post the terminal output as well as the content of `headers.txt`.

Comment: @Gilles I have added the content of headers.txt at /home, in the question itself.

Comment: It's very smart to post that you're using The Pirate Bay in public! ;)

Comment: @richard I have changed the content of the /var/www/index.html and thepiratebay.se is now showing the new content of index.html

Answer (score 2):

There is something pesky on your DNS answer. The correct one should be:

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
thepiratebay.se.    84496   IN  A   194.71.107.27
```

It seems that someone is "shadowing" that to you.

Comment: Yes, definitely that. But why does `host thepiratebay.se` return the correct address while `dig thepiratebay.se` returns 127.0.0.1?

Comment: @Gilles --- I do not know. Could the OP have more than one host in `/etc/resolv.conf`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should first make sure that it shows /var/www/index.html or just a basic apache2 server.
You can change permission of the file with `chmod +rw /var/www/index.html`. That should give you read and write permission. Then try changing it and go back to piratebay.se and look if that changed. Your apache2 server is off, so it isn't likely to change. I think a router, a firewall or a proxy directs you to this page. Is it the only page that can

If you can run commands as root (with`su` or `sudo`) try running `sudo apt-get install dnsutils` as the console suggests. You could try to chmod as root.

About the difference between 127.0.0.1 and 127.0.1.1 from [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/363095/why-does-my-hostname-appear-with-the-address-127-0-1-1-rather-than-127-0-0-1-in):

> There isn't a great deal of difference between the two; 127/8 (eg: 127.0.0.0 => 127.255.255.255) are all bound to the loopback interface.
>
> The reason why is documented in the Debian manual here: http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch05.en.html#_the_hostname_resolution
>
> Ultimately, it is a bug workaround; the original report is here: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=316099

So it's not an issue it's just a workaround, thus you can't fix it, it's working.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all your tech support. I fixed the issue myself with a long range research and faith to fix it. And of course without the hint of information that you guys gave, it wouldn't have been possible.

I installed nautilus and opened it from terminal as sudo.

sudo nautilus

It asked my password and I entered it.
And in nautilus, I deleted the WWW folder at /var, and now thepiratebay.se is working fine.

Thanks again for all your support and answering my naive questions!!